# Can't access variables inside parenthesis in bash

Tags: bash, macos, variables, if-statement

In bash, if I run

```
(foo=14)
```

And then try to reference that variable later on in my bash script:

```
echo "${foo}"
```

I don't get anything. How can I make bash store this variable the way I need it to?

Specifically, I am using this in an if statement and checking the exit code, something kind of like:

```
if (bar="$(foo=14;echo "${foo}"|tr '1' 'a' 2>&1)")
then
    echo "Setting "'$bar'" was a success. It is ${bar}"
else
    echo "Setting "'$bar'" failed with a nonzero exit code."
fi
```

Comment: What's the point of using parentheses in this case? I don't see any need for an additional subshell. Also, I think there is no point in querying the exit code of `tr`. AFIK, `tr` always returns exit code 0 if it reads from stdin and has not been called with invalid options. In your case, I don't see a possibility that the `else` branch would be taken.

Comment: @user1934428 That was just a simple example. In reality, my if statement is much more daunting and complex than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commands enclosed in parenthesis e.g. `()` are executed in a sub-shell. Any assignment in a sub-shell will not exist outside that sub-shell.

```
foo=14
bar=$(echo $foo | tr '1' 'a' )
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "Setting "'$bar'" was a success. It is ${bar}"
else
    echo "Setting "'$bar'" failed with a nonzero exit code."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks suspectus, this so far seems to work ok. Could you explain what the `if [ "$bar" ]` is checking for?, and isn't `[[ .... ]]` preferred nowadays instead?

Comment: I've changed the test to match the message. The test is that the `tr` command exits without error. In that case $? is 0. Regarding [[ ]] and [] debate, yes both in this case. I work with a lot of older shells so I default to the older [] at times.

Comment: Just that, as I mentioned above, **this** `tr` will never fail, unless some malevolent sould removed it from /usr/bin, so the `if` is IMO useless.